# HERE autocomplete API exclude result types (street, houseNumber etc)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, here-api, here-autocomplete, here-maps-rest

HERE autocomplete API request when made on `9535` returns 5 results which all match on result type `street` instead of `postalCode` as they do with Google Maps by default. e.g.

```
https://autocomplete.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_code=MYAPPID&app_id=MYAPPCODE&country=USA&query=9535

{
  "label": "United States, ID, Elk City, NF-9535",
  "language": "en",
  "countryCode": "USA",
  "locationId": "NT_OA7lb1uPsSru.j2wCzrKCC",
  "address": {
    "country": "United States",
    "state": "ID",
    "county": "Idaho",
    "city": "Elk City",
    "street": "NF-9535",
    "postalCode": "83525"
  },
  "matchLevel": "street"
}
```

**Is there a way to make HERE maps autocomplete API exclude specific result types or on the flip side is there a way to only include specific types?**

Currently `areas` does not work for me since I need as I said `9535` to return result types of `postalCode` instead of street but I want `2300 Maple` to still match `street` types.

I know we can `prefix` the `9535` with `ca 9535` and then the expected results are returned:

```
{
  "label": "United States, CA, Stanislaus, 95350, Modesto",
  "language": "en",
  "countryCode": "USA",
  "locationId": "NT_-8QfFb8eUnn6Kb1FGJPYKD",
  "address": {
    "country": "United States",
    "state": "CA",
    "county": "Stanislaus",
    "city": "Modesto",
    "postalCode": "95350"
  },
  "matchLevel": "postalCode"
}
```

But that is not a very good option since the majority of the users would expect the `Google Maps` behavior.

**Is there a ranking on the result types maybe**?

Answer (score 1):

yes there is a brand new beta feature for Autocomplete. Please add the `&resultType=postalcode` in combination with the country=USA That should help give only postal codes.

E.g.

```
http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=[add your app_id]&app_code=[add your app_code]&query=9535&language=de&resultType=postalcode&country=USA
```

We will update the documentation concerning this topic soon.

Comment: This is not what I want. Not sure you read the entire question. By doing that next time I type “2300” I will NOT get “2300 Maple Ave” as a suggestion since I only return PostalCodes now.

Comment: I see your point. Then this parameter will not help you here. But I am afraid that there is no further possibility to have an influence on the ranking of the Autocomplete API.